# polymorphism, virtual methods, C++

Tags: c++, polymorphism, virtual, member

```
class A;
{
private:
    int a;
public:
    virtual int getV() { return a; }
} a;

class C : public A;
{
private:
    int c;
public:
    int getV() { return c; }
} c;

class D
{
public:
   A* liste;
} d;
```

Memory for liste may be allocated and A::a and C::c are holding values. Now if I put c in D::liste[0] and give it out with

```
cout << d.liste[0].getV();
```

it prints A::a. Why doesn't it print out C::c although I declared A::getV() as virtual?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C++ polymorphism works only for pointers and references. `liste[0]` has type `A`, not `A*` or `A&`, so the `liste[0].getV()` call is not dispatched virtually. It just calls `A::getV()`.

Comment: thanks! what would be the best/common solution for this problem?

Comment: @LPrulzcrossover If you want to have polymorphic behavior, you should use references or pointers. For example `A* ptr = &c; ptr->getV()`; would print `C::c`.

Comment: For me both VS10 express and gcc 4.4.7, do the polymorphism also for arrays. means: `ptr[0].getv()` gives the same value as  `ptr->getv()`. it's not clear from the question what was the problem. need to give full not working code, but I guess he tried to reach from A object to C...

Answer (score 1):

I wrote the program like this and getting the correct result as expected

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class A
{
 private:
    int a;
 public:
    virtual int getV() { cout<<"A";return a; }
};

class C : public A
{
 private:
 int c;
 public:
   virtual int getV() { cout<<"C";return c; }
};

class D
{
  public:
    A* liste[2];
};

int main()
{
  D d;
  d.liste[0]=new C();
  d.liste[1]=new A();
  cout<<d.liste[0]->getV();      
  return 0;
}
```

Just have a look at it..

Comment: thanks! In `D` you could also use `A** liste` in order to keep it dynamical, don't you?

Comment: yeah we can do that.. but i just saying that how the program worked.